# Potential Security Issues with Passing Wordpress Variable as a Parameter on get_permalink()

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to make sure I'm not opening up a security hole in my site. I have a Custom Post Type called "Communities" and a custom post type called "Floor Plans" and need to add a parameter to the URL on Single Floorplan posts.

My goal is that when a Floorplan post object is selected from a Communities Single post, it appends the name of the community (i.e. single community post title) to the URL for use on the following page. So, enabling query vars:

```
    <?php

    //* Enable queryvars (functions.php)

    add_filter('query_vars', 'parameter_queryvars' );
    function parameter_queryvars( $qvars )
    {
    $qvars[] = "community";
    return $qvars;
    }
```

I have a template part called "dynamic-floor-plans" that lives in a loop at the bottom of Single Communities posts. I'm grabbing the single_post_title of the current communities page, and passing that to the URL so that it's available using $_GET

The reason we opted for this method is that the "Floor Plans" post type has a canonical/default version that has the same properties as its Community-specific counterparts. In order to avoid a post relationship situation (which would give the user flat out wrong data in some cases) the community versions just have to be able to use

```
  <?php

  //* dynamic-floor-plans template part (placed in loop on communities page)

  global $post;
  $string = strtolower(single_post_title( null, false ));
  $slug = str_replace(' ','-',$string);
  ?>

     <div class="card-button">
      <a class="small expanded secondary button" 
        href="<?php echo get_the_permalink() . '?community=' . $slug ?>">View Floorplan</a>
   </div>
```

Now, this totally is working. I'm able to grab that community variable on the subsequently-selected floorplan single page using $_GET and things seem to be working nicely on the front end:

```
    <?php
    //*  Single Floorplans Template

    $community = $_GET["community"];

    ?>
      <h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo $title ?></h1>
      <h4>
        <?php if ($community) { ?> 
          At <?php echo $community; }  ?>
     </h4>
     ...
```

I just can't help but feel that this isn't kosher, or that there's a more secure way to do this.

Am I open to exploitation? I can include the function for the loop itself as well, but figure this code will be sufficient to get started in evaluation.